# How can I set my my console title to increase if an "if statement" succeeds or fails

Tags: c#

So, what I am trying to do is create a math game, so the way I did it, is 1- I present the math question, 2- I receive user-input of the solution, 3- I compare the user's answer to my answer using an if statement, now, what I am trying to do is to set some kind of counter in my console's title in order to increase when I get a question wrong or right, so, can anyone give a suggestion on how to do that.

I have tried to set integers and use them in the title, but I can not use integers in console.title, I have also tried manually writing it, but I can not be certain if the user gets the answer correct or wrong the first round.

```
using Figgle;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Math
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = ("Let's Learn Math");
            Console.WriteLine(
            FiggleFonts.Standard.Render("Welcome to the"));
            Console.WriteLine(
            FiggleFonts.Standard.Render("Math Games"));

            int milliseconds = 5000;
            Thread.Sleep(milliseconds);

            Console.Clear();

            int myInt;
            Console.WriteLine("Write the answer of 1842 * 34");
            myInt = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (myInt == 62628)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(
                FiggleFonts.Standard.Render("Correct!"));

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(
                FiggleFonts.Standard.Render("Wrong"));
            }

            int milliseconds2 = 5000;
            Thread.Sleep(milliseconds2);
            Console.Clear();

            int myInt2;
            Console.WriteLine("Write the answer of 2689 * 15");
            myInt2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (myInt2 == 40335)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(
                FiggleFonts.Standard.Render("Correct!"));

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(
                    FiggleFonts.Standard.Render("Wrong"));
            }
            int milliseconds3 = 5000;
            Thread.Sleep(milliseconds3);
            Console.Clear();

        }
    }
}
```

So, I expect the counter to increase with either correct or wrong, so the title changes to "Let's Learn Math | Correct = ? | Wrong = ?"

Comment: *I can not use integers in console.title*. Sure you can. `Console.Title = $"Correct: {someIntegerVariable}"`. By the way, you should look into using loops in your application. Copying/pasting duplicate blocks of code is not a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

It should be fairly simple. First, declare a variable to keep track of the total count of correct answers:

```
int correctAnswers = 0;
```

Then, when the user gets an answer correct, increment this variable and use it as part of the Console's title text:

```
if (userAnsweredCorrectly)
{
    correctAnswers++;
    Console.Title = $"You have answered {correctAnswers} questions correctly";
}
```

Comment: Oh, thanks you, I tried doing something like but I couldn't get an integer into the title, I tried placeholders but it didn't work, guess this works as well :) thanks.